# Turning off variable substitution on import of XML body

Tags: xml, paw-app

I use Paw extensively to POST/GET/PUT a REST endpoint.  It is a truly amazing tool and enjoy using it.  I recently opened up and created a new request, I use Text for the Body with XML as the data.  Importing a new body.
The text fields had a series of green boxes and tried treating them as variables to be substituted.

[image: screen capture of issue]

That doesn't even make sense.  It's XML not some strange exotic language.  Is it possible to disable substitution and post what I pasted in?

Comment: This is a large blemish on an otherwise awesome tool.

Answer (score 2):

Use Edit -> Paste Raw Value (on Mac: Cmd+Alt+Shift+V) to paste your original XML document without any variable substitution.